# History: What was the Lemma? (Grothendieck Harvard Lectures; Mumford)

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ct.category-theory, ho.history-overview

In an article about the life of Grothendieck, available here:

http://www.ams.org/notices/200409/fea-grothendieck-part1.pdf

Allyn Jackson writes about how Mumford was profoundly impressed:

Mumford found the leaps into abstraction to be breathtaking. Once he asked Grothendieck how to prove a certain lemma and got in reply a highly abstract argument. Mumford did not at first believe that such an  abstract  argument could  prove  so  concrete  a lemma. “Then I went away and thought about it for a couple of days, and I realized it was exactly right,” Mumford  recalled.

What were the lemma and proof that so impressed Mumford?

(I have tried asking algebraic geometers and category theorists; the tags attached to this question are speculative.)

Comment: This post could be better at home on [hsm.se], though it is probably not off-topic here, either.

Comment: Based on things I've heard people say, I would guess something close to the Theorem of the Cube from Abelian Varieties.

Comment: Why not ask Mumford?

Comment: If nobody collects the bounty I will ask Mumford directly.

Comment: Asking Mumford directly is almost surely the best idea. If you want a guess, then I suspect it is Zariski’s theorem that "the inverse image of every normal point under a proper birational morphism from one variety onto another is connected" as described [**here**](http://www.dam.brown.edu/people/mumford/beyond/papers/2014b--Recollections-AGroth.pdf) (p. 4).

Comment: If you get an answer tell us!

Comment: I wrote to Mumford and will post any answer I get.

Comment: @BenjaminDickman, that seems worth posting as an answer

Comment: @DikranKaragueuzian Did you ever get a response?

Answer (score 26):

The concrete lemma was ["The Theorem of The Cube"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theorem_of_the_cube), (Mumford, Abelian Varieties [AV], Section 6) as indicated by Tabes Bridges.  The abstract argument was the second theorem in Section 5 of AV (p.46).

In Mumford's collected works, Volume 2, p. 689 there is a letter of Grothendieck to Mumford in which the abstract argument is discussed, and footnote 2 indicates that it was published by Mumford in AV as the second theorem in Chapter 5.

All of this was confirmed in an email correspondence with Mumford.

I am obliged Mumford (of course), to Tabes Bridges for giving the right answer and to Benjamin Dickman for a reminder to post.  I should look at MO more frequently!